# carouFredSel is not a function error

Tags: jquery, html

I'm struggling to set up carouFredSel. I'm doing everything correctly - all links work. I'm adding this on online store using smarty templates. I get this error in the chrome console:

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).carouFredSel is not a function

head section of **header.tpl**:

```
<!-- jQuery -->       
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<!-- CarouFredSel -->
<script src="http://serwer1449841.home.pl/autoinstalator/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

{literal}
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
          jQuery('#carousel').carouFredSel({
                items                : 2,
                direction            : "up",
                scroll : {
                    items            : 1,
                    easing            : "elastic",
                    duration        : 1000,
                    pauseOnHover    : true
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
{/literal}
```

**footer.tpl**:

```
<div id='carousel'>
    <img src='http://example.com/img1.png' width='105' />
    <img src='http://example.com/img2.png' width='110' />
    <img src='http://example.com/img3.png' width='105' />
    <img src='http://example.com/img4.png' width='120' />
    <img src='http://example.com/img5.png' width='105' />
    <img src='http://example.com/img6.png' width='200' />
</div>
```

**css**

```
#carousel img {
    padding: 16px 10px 14px 10px;
}

#carousel {
    width: 1178px;
    height: 126px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Path to caroufredsel is correct, what am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and this answer helped me
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=879298#c3

```html
<ol>
  <li>jQuery loaded into DOM</li>
  <li>caroFredSel plugin is attached to jQuery in DOM</li>
  <li>Something is causing ANOTHER instance of jQuery to load into the DOM, overwriting the previous $ object.</li>
  <li>When caroFredSel() is called on the $ object in carousel.js, since it is a new jQ object, the method doesn't exist.</li>
</ol>
```

Hope this help you too